# Fechas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Necesito una consulta de SQL Server que me traiga los registros desde las 7 am del día anterior hasta las 11 am del día de la fecha. Yo tengo esta consulta, pero necesitaría mejorarla:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1
WHERE FEC between getdate() -1 and getdate() '11:00:00.000'
```

Comment: "desde el día anterior", a qué hora?, misma hora de este instante?

Comment: perdón, desde las 7 am del día anterior hasta las 11 am del día siguiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL Server no existe una manera sencilla de truncar los tipos de dato fecha/hora. Lo que hacemos, es tomar la diferencia de la porción a la que se quiere truncar (en este caso días) respecto a una fecha específica y luego sumar esa diferencia a la fecha específica. Comúnmente, uso la fecha 0 que es '1900-01-01'.

Dejo un ejemplo de como calcular las fechas. En la primera, restamos uno a la cantidad de días que vamos a sumar porque queremos el día de ayer. En la segunda, sumamos las 11 horas adicionales.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0),
       DATEADD( HH, 11, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
```

Con esas fechas calculadas, podemos corregir la clausula `WHERE`. Nota, después del comentario que se hizo en la pregunta, corregí el cálculo de la primer fecha para iniciar a las 7am.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLA1
WHERE FEC BETWEEN DATEADD( HH,  7, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
              AND DATEADD( HH, 11, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
```

Comment: Me re sirvió, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: la forma fácil de "truncar" la fecha a nivel día sería convertirlo a `date`. Por otro lado, es recomendable no usar `GETDATE() - 1`, sino `DATEDIFF`, así como evitar las abreviaciones `HH,DD,etc` y usar `HOUR,DAY,etc`. De todas formas, +1 por la respuesta